Symmetry of partial derivatives.
Let $f:R^2\to R$. Suppose f is of class $C^1$, $\partial^2 f / \partial x \partial y$ exists and is continuous.
I want to show that (1) $\partial^2 f / \partial y \partial x$ exists and is continuous with $\epsilon-\delta$ argument (Or any other rigorous proof is okay), (2) $\partial^2 f / \partial x \partial y = \partial^2 f / \partial y \partial x$.
My Idea
(1) Existence of $\partial^2f / \partial y \partial x$
Denote $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ by $g$. Then to show that $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y \partial x}$ exists, we just need to show that $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}g$ exists. For any $(x_0,y_0)\in R^2$, I thought that
$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial y}g(x_0,y_0) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{g(x_0,y_0+h)-g(x_0,y_0)}{h}.$$
Then if such limit exists, given $\epsilon>0$, we need $\delta>0$ such that
$$|h|<\delta \Longrightarrow \left| \frac{g(x_0,y_0+h)-g(x_0,y_0)}{h} \right|<\epsilon.$$
I have no idea about how to set such $\delta$. Since $g$ is continuous, if there is no $h$ in the denominator, the $\epsilon-\delta$ argument is trivial. But $h$ in the denominator makes me confused.
(2) Continuity of $\partial^2f / \partial y \partial x$
If $\partial^2f / \partial y \partial x$ is continuous, then given $\epsilon>0$, we need $\delta>0$ such that
$$||(x,y)-(x_0,y_0)|| \Longrightarrow ||\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial y \partial x}(x,y)-\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial y \partial x}(x_0,y_0)||<\epsilon.$$
Since I'm not even finishing (1), I have no idea about (2).

Do you know Schwarz's theorem on the symmetry of second partial derivatives?

Thanks I finished the proof!
